# Can't read Swagger JSON, API Docs

Tags: jhipster

I have created our custom application using JHipster as a local installation.
I am able to get all working, as in I am able to create a user, add a row in one of the entities.

But when access the API, I get the below error.

> Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs

Is there any specific configuration we have to do to be able to access the API documentation?

Comment: What happens when you access that URL in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to do, it should be available in your "admin" menu. Then you might have hit an bug, but we haven't had any issue about Swagger for months.

Comment: HI We are able to fix this issue, but we have to do the following changes and only after that we are able to load the SWAGGER API url    in SecurityConfiguration.java we had pre-fix our applicaiton name as follows      ".antMatchers("<ourappmame>"/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()" and then again in WebConfigurer.java we have to do the same as folllows   "source.registerCorsConfiguration("/<ourappname>/v2/api-docs",config);".

Comment: So after doing the above changes we are able to access SWAGGER API url from Admin menu.  But i am not quite sure whether is it expected to be done by us  as i am not able to see any mention of that in documentation.    Pls. suggest and thanks in advance